# Angular - inside an ng-repeat, checkbox state to affect only one element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

If I have for example a simple todo list:

**HTML**

```
<ul ng-repeat="todos in keyVar.list">
  <li ng-class="{ 'completed' : keyVar.toggle }">
       {{ todos }}
     <input ng-if="!keyVar.toggle" type = "checkbox" ng-click="keyVar.toggle=true" >
     <input ng-if="keyVar.toggle" type = "checkbox" checked= "true" ng-click="keyVar.toggle=false" ></input>
   </li>
</ul>
```

**JS**

```
angular.module("todoApp", [])
 .controller("mainCtrl", function(){

    var keyVar = this;

     keyVar.title ="Angular Todos";
     keyVar.list=[];
     keyVar.toggle = false;


     keyVar.todosArr = function(){
       keyVar.list.push(keyVar.todo)
       keyVar.todo = "";
     }
});
```

When I run this, I can add a todo, and check and uncheck the checkbox which toggles a class of completed, but it gives the class to every todo and if I check one checkbox, all of them go checked. I think I have to use something like keyVar.list[$index]? But I'm not sure where to use it or how.

Comment: you should define for any checkbox separate  `ng-model`.

Comment: Hi, you have only one element for the checkkbox... you should have one bool per each element that you need to bind

Answer (score 1):

Try like this. I define for each todo a `status`. and bind that to checkbox. when user click on checkbox change it.

```js
angular.module("todoApp", [])
 .controller("mainCtrl", function(){

    var keyVar = this;

     keyVar.title ="Angular Todos";
      keyVar.list=[
         {
            "title":"Todo1",
            "status":false
         },
         {
            "title":"Todo2",
            "status":false
         }
     ];


     keyVar.todosArr = function(){
       keyVar.list.push({title:keyVar.todo,status:false})
       keyVar.todo = "";
     }
});
```

```css
.completed{
     text-decoration: line-through;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="todoApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl as keyVar" class="container">
 
  <input type="text" ng-model="keyVar.todo">
  <button ng-click="keyVar.todosArr()">Add Todo</button>
  <ul ng-repeat="todos in keyVar.list">
  <li ng-class="{ 'completed' : todos.status }">
       {{ todos.title }}
   <input ng-model="todos.status" type = "checkbox" ng-click="keyVar.toggle=true" >
   </li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Comment: Well that works for todos that I hard code on the script, not for ones added dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Try use ng-checked instead of ng-click.

```
<input ng-if="!keyVar.toggle" ng-checked="keyVar.toggle=true">
```

Comment: It's weird because doing that individual checkboxes do get created for each element but their state in the console is always true or false, it doesn't change when I check or uncheck them so it won't apply the class.

Comment: O i see. That is because the checkbox cannot identify itself when you clicked it. I think the best solution is that when you 're click it, you call the click method and send id as parameter. In the click method, loop through array to find the giving id.